# Why is gravity not a force?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, gravity, spacetime, curvature

Gravitation is the mutual attraction of masses, yet Einstein showed it is how spacetime is curved by mass and how mass moves in relation to this curvature. Why then do we still consider gravitation a "force"?

Comment: See [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/254352/) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61899/).

Answer (score 1):

The need for the concept of "fundamental force" comes from quantum mechanics, where a fundamental force is assigned a coupling constant that enters the quantum mechanically modeled interactions. Mainstream physics  assumes   a form of  general relativity that is quantized, and quantization needs a coupling constant for the interaction with the space time of GR.

At present GR is not definitively quantized;  an effective quantization of gravity(GR) is used  in most cosmological model efforts.  That is why the term "fundamental force" is used for gravity.

[These are the coupling  constants](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html) for all the mainstream "forces" that are used in quantum mechanical theoretical models.

[image: funforc]

Comment: The trouble is that this has become disconnected from the real world, where "force" is what a force gauge measures. I have no problem with generalizing the concept to forces with microscopic range, but you should include the Pauli force, the force that resists the compression of condensed matter, easily seen in experiments and everyday life.

Comment: No, the Pauli does not have the  same function in the mainstream standard model of physics. It can be interpreted as a macroscopic type "force", but not as fundamental in the  in the sense above. There is no coupling constant associated in the QFT.

Comment: That's what I mean by "disconnected". Of course it's fundamental: the phenomena are fundamental to physics, the abstractions are not. A physics that denies that an effect you can measure with a force gauge is a force has lost touch with the physical world. A force gauge doesn't measure coupling constants.

Comment: In the language used by mainstream physics for the  elementary particles QFT, it does by definition.

Comment: How did "mainstream physics" cease to be about the phenomena of the physical world?

Comment: If you're honest about physics, you can't define away phenomena you don't wish to address.

Comment: @JohnDoty I don't think anybody is defining phenomena away.  The disagreement is how to categorize Pauli exclusion force.  I was under the impression that it was an emergent property of the fundamental forces, and for that reason it's not categorized as fundamental, even if it is extremely important (solidity of matter and all that).

Comment: @hegel5000 The phenomena are fundamental, they do not emerge from the abstractions of theory. Even in the theory, the Pauli force does not depend on any other force for its existence.

Comment: @JohnDoty in order for physics to have a consistent mathematical theory, it **has to define**  terms which can only come from the language we all use. In the quantum mechanical theories **fundamental force** is used in the sense I describe in my answer. One could invent new terms that have no meaning in everyday language, but that is not the way it has been done.

Comment: @annav Physics is not mathematics. Mathematics is merely a tool, and, indeed, **not** a fundamental one. The phenomena are in charge. It is critical for physics to respect the phenomena. Calling mathematical abstractions fundamental forces is upside down. You need a definition? A fundamental force is what a force gauge measures. That's a **physical** definition.

Answer (score 1):

> [gravity] is not really a force at all

This [is true and it isn't](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/744524), but beside the point anyway as we're best talking about fundamental *interactions*, not *forces*, so as to include decays. The weak interaction, for example, *does* exert forces, but they're so feeble it primarily matters because of the decays it causes.

> Isn't the "true" fundamental interaction that between mass and spacetime?

@annav's answer already noted fundamental interactions are of quantum-mechanical significance. There are [any number of reasons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6980) gravity must be quantum. Therefore, GR must emerge from the effects of gravitons. The most fundamental account of gravity is therefore in terms of how particle interactions affect the spacetime in which particle interactions are suited. (However, there's [a bit more](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1080) to being a fundamental interaction than having a particle-based - or to be more precise, field-based - explanation.)

> Is this because some physicists don't really believe in GR?

Having said all that, even if the universe weren't quantum in the slightest, it *still* would make sense to consider gravity a fundamental interaction. Such a universe would have "classical" field theories for electromagnetism and gravity, and the latter would be GR or [an alternative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternatives_to_general_relativity). It would be a gauge theory like EM, except based on diffeomorphism invariance rather than local $U(1)$. Field theories' Lagrangians' kinetic terms would use an alternative to partial derivatives that adds two kinds of term, those proportional to the EM field for EM, plus those proportional to Christoffel symbols for GR. See also [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/340371) & [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/665273) for further parallels.